# How to identify variables with prognostic predictive value?

Tags: predictive-models, survival, lasso, biostatistics, medicine

We have collected biopsy data and clinical data from 232 patients. The are in total 45 different clinical and histopathological variables available. What statistical method(s) is recommended to identify variables with prognostic predictive value? Is LASSO regression an option?

Comment: Please provide additional data to help determine the best approach. What outcome are you trying to assess?

Comment: Have you looked into multivariate analysis? With these variables, you could perform PCA to see if somehow you have an overall clustering based on the outcomes. This would be my first step.